# symfony / doctrine : entity wont delete

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine

I have this code in Symfony 3:

```
(...)
        $annonceActive = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:AnnonceActive')
                            ->find($SomeKnownId);
        $profilPresta = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Profil')
        ->find($SomeKnownId);

        $annonceEnCours = new AnnonceEnCours();
        $this->get('app_annonce_transportateur')
        ->transporterAnnonce($annonceActive, $annonceEnCours);

        $annonceEnCours->setPresta($profilPresta);
        $em->remove($annonceActive);
        $em->persist($annonceEnCours);
        $em->flush();


        dump($annonceActive); 
        //annonceActive stills exists !!
```

Now I have the service used :

```
class TransportateurElementAnnonce 
{
    protected $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager){
        $this->em = $entityManager;
    }

    protected function copierInfosAnnonceVersAnnonce(&$annonceSource, &$annonceTarget)
    {
        $annonceTarget->setAuteur($annonceSource->getAuteur());
        $annonceTarget->setPresta($annonceSource->getPresta());
        $annonceTarget->setCompetence($annonceSource->getCompetence());
        $annonceTarget->setGroupeCompetence($annonceSource->getGroupeCompetence());
        $annonceTarget->setTitre($annonceSource->getTitre());
        $annonceTarget->setSlug($annonceSource->getSlug());
        $annonceTarget->setDescription($annonceSource->getDescription());
        $annonceTarget->setPrix($annonceSource->getPrix());
        $annonceTarget->setServiceADistance($annonceSource->getServiceADistance());
        $annonceTarget->setDateCreation($annonceSource->getDateCreation());
    }

    public function transporterAnnonce(&$annonceSource, &$annonceTarget)
    {
        $this->copierInfosAnnonceVersAnnonce($annonceSource, $annonceTarget);

        $this->em->persist($annonceSource);
        $this->em->persist($annonceTarget);
        $this->em->remove($annonceSource);
        $this->em->flush();
    }

}
```

How can I use $em->remove($annonceActive) in the controller, and still have an object !

I really tried everything, I dont get it.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Why are you calling `$this->em->persist($annonceSource)` when you’re removing it two lines later?

Comment: I would try to remove the lines of code with $em in your service, look how the code behaves without it, just use $em in your controller

Comment: It does not matter whether you execute this code directly in the controller (ugh) or inside any object graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution was given by @jacek : I remove all interaction with the entity manager in the service, and used it only in the controller.

My service looks like before, except I dont use entity manager !

Thanks guys for the precious help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `clone` to "copy" an object, that way you can use the copied object after you've changed the original using the entity manager (or whatever you want to do with it).

```
$originalObject = new SomeClass();
$clonedObject = clone $originalObject;

// Change the original object here, for example use it with the entity manager..
$originalObject->setWhatever('bla');
$this->em->persist($originalObject);
$this->em->flush();

// At this point $clonedObject is still unchanged.
```

More information on cloning objects: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php

Hope this helps..

Comment: This may have unexpected side effects since both objects will share collection objects should they use any. There're [dedicated packages](https://github.com/myclabs/DeepCopy) for object cloning available which do the cloning a lot better.

Comment: annonceActive and annonceEnCours  does not belong to the same class !
So I dont want to clone the object